# "can't access the server_dir" error when trying to share a directory

Tags: nfs

I have installed NFS server and Client on separate machines.
The problem is when i mount the shared directory on client side 
using command

> mount server_addr:server_dir client_dir

But it gives an error saying that

> don't have permission to share this directory (can't access the server_dir)

Though I have given read-write (rw) permissions to the client by updating
/etc/exports file in server as

> server_dir client_ip(rw,sync,no_root_squash)

But still giving error as access denied on client side. I have also done an `exportfs`.

Any kind of help/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I can share directories using same steps if server and client is on the same machine but if they are on different then its giving error.

Answer (score 2):

Set few permissions on.. (related to firewall)

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F
```